# Sending DM with embeds using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have tried many things but I can't get `discord.py` to send a message with embeds. But I have gotten it to send a normal message when a command is typed using this code.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content

  if msg.startswith('$helpme'):
    await message.author.send("this text would be sent via dm, but with no embeds...")
```

It would be a help menu which the bot would the dm the user when $helpme is typed. Problem is I can't get it to send this embed code.

```
  embed=discord.Embed(title=" Help", description="I am here to help!", color=0x0000ff)
  embed.set_author(name="Meerdus", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/834885490451808286/939646209092616312/M.png")
  embed.add_field(name="$helpme", value="Shows this menu!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$kick", value="Kick a member if you have Administrator permissions!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$ban", value="Ban a member if you have Administrator permissions!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$unban", value="Unban a member if you have Administrator permissions.", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$lock", value="Lock a channel if you have the permission to manage channels!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$meme", value="Display a random clean meme! :)", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$doggo", value="Show a random dog picture and dog fact!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$kitty", value="Show a random cat picture and cat fact!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$birdy", value="Show a random bird picture and bird fact!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$randomnum", value="Display a random number between 1 and 100!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$tictactoe", value="Play tictactoe with two people by specifing <command> <yourusername> <secondplayersusername>", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="DONT ACTUALLY ENTER THE <>", value="You have to enter the things said inside them.", inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is it needs to be `await message.author.send()` not `await ctx.send()` since in the code snippet that works it is in the `on_message()` event listener. `ctx.send()` is how you would do it in a Bot command. The syntaxation is completely fine.

For example in my own discord bot you can see [I send the help embed inside a cog the exact same way as the second snippet](https://github.com/a5taroth/the-rock-bot/blob/v1.0/src/modules/help.py) which is completely functional.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using a bot command, you don't use **ctx**. This is also mainly because you haven't passed (told the function about) ctx. Instead, use `message.author.send()`.

See the examples below:

```
message.author.send(embed=embed) # Send to the author
message.channel.send(embed=embed) # Send to the channel
```

Comment: Hey @Trent112232
I am still having an issue, now my $helpme command works and it sends the embed to my dms. But, now all of my other commands don't work! :/ Thank you for your response!

Comment: @atwoyearold14 Try putting client.process_commands(message) at the end of on_message

Comment: I'm not sure where you are talking about...
I tried to put it here:
client.process_commands(message)
    await message.author.send(embed=embed)

And I also tried here
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  client.process_commands(message)
  msg = message.content

But both still did the same thing, the dm thing worked, but the other commands didn't work.

Comment: Put it at the end of the entire function, i.e after ctx.send(embed=embed)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ctx.send` use `ctx.author.send`

```py
  embed=discord.Embed(title=" Help", description="I am here to help!", color=0x0000ff)
  embed.set_author(name="Meerdus", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/834885490451808286/939646209092616312/M.png")
  embed.add_field(name="$helpme", value="Shows this menu!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$kick", value="Kick a member if you have Administrator permissions!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$ban", value="Ban a member if you have Administrator permissions!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$unban", value="Unban a member if you have Administrator permissions.", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$lock", value="Lock a channel if you have the permission to manage channels!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$meme", value="Display a random clean meme! :)", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$doggo", value="Show a random dog picture and dog fact!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$kitty", value="Show a random cat picture and cat fact!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$birdy", value="Show a random bird picture and bird fact!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$randomnum", value="Display a random number between 1 and 100!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="$tictactoe", value="Play tictactoe with two people by specifing <command> <yourusername> <secondplayersusername>", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="DONT ACTUALLY ENTER THE <>", value="You have to enter the things said inside them.", inline=False)
  await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
```